# How to modify node.js stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, stream

I am streaming an xml file from S3. I need to build a new xml file with a different structure for sphinx search engine. I am already streaming the file from S3, piping it into my SAX parser but now I need to figure out how I can make modifications to the stream (after the SAX parser) and upload to S3.

```
parser.on('startElement', function(name, attrs) {
    // Do something
});
```

I found what seems to be a great S3 library that streams called [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox), so I am currently using that library. I'm not stuck on this library, just what I found that seems to be decent. The code that they have to stream data to S3 in the example, is only from an HTTP request. I am relatively new to streams, since I have a PHP background.

Knox Example Stream:

```
http.get('http://google.com/doodle.png', function(res){
  var headers = {
      'Content-Length': res.headers['content-length']
    , 'Content-Type': res.headers['content-type']
  };
  client.putStream(res, '/doodle.png', headers, function(err, res){
    // Logic
  });
});
```

I am thinking I would need to do something on the lines of this.

```
parser.on('startElement', function(name, attrs) {

  var headers = {
      'Content-Length': res.headers['content-length']
    , 'Content-Type': res.headers['content-type']
  };
  client.putStream(res, '/doodle.png', headers, function(err, res){
    // Logic
  });

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Node?

Answer (score 2):

[This discussion of Node's new streams](http://calv.info/an-introduction-to-nodes-new-streams/) speaks explicitly about transforming streams from S3.

*NB: This is in reference to streams as implemented in Node 0.10.x*

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.org/package/through

This module will do what you need.